# How to randomly choose one div out of a group and assign an event to it

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to randomly choose one div out of a group and assign a click event to just the selected one. Below is the code I wrote thus far.

```
<div id="div1"> </div>
<div id="div2"> </div>
<div id="div3"> </div>
<div id="div4"> </div>

<script>

var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("div3");
var div4 = document.getElementById("div4");



var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

var bomb = "div" + randomnumber;


alert(bomb);

bomb.onclick = function() { alert("You clicked me...BOOM!")}; // does not work


</script>
```

Comment: (4 - 1 + 1) is a bit superfluous - why not just (4)?

Comment: This is where I got that from. There is a full explanation in the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range

Comment: Ah ok - in the example they're showing a generic way to generate a random number within a range.  If you're using fixed values (i.e. these max and mins don't change at runtime) it's best to stick in the actual numbers - I expect you won't get any difference in performance as most compilers would optimise this anyway, but it makes the code a bit cleaner & easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the `onclick` property of the string bomb, not the element.

Use

```
document.getElementById(bomb).onclick = function() { alert("You clicked me...BOOM!")};
```

You may also use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) if you don't want to replace existing click listeners :

```
document.getElementById(bomb).addEventListener(function() {
   alert("You clicked me...BOOM!")
});
```

Comment: The 'onclick' property shouldn't be used yet that's what the OP uses. Upvoted.

Comment: I know , but I wasn't sure how to "convert it". I guess I should also ask how to make this an "eventListener" instead per dystroy's comment

Answer (score 0):

If that is your actual script try this:

```
var bomb = window['div' + randomnumber].onclick = function(){alert('You clicked me... BOOM!');};
```

If this isn't the actual script, just replace `window[` with `this[`, to reference whatever the current context is.

Of course, @dystroy's approach works just fine, too. I just added this to show you a way to reference a variable, using a string